# How to obtain the bibtex item for a question with a program or HTTP request?

Tags: support, app-request, script-request

Which request should my program send to mathoverflow.net to get the bibtex, which is so well hidden behind the share button?

Rephrased: what I'm after is something analogous to a link like:

[adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=2011arXiv1111.3349P&data_type=BIBTEX](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=2011arXiv1111.3349P&data_type=BIBTEX)

which serves the bibtex for arXiv articles.

### Disclaimer:

I asked the very same question also at [meta.mathoverflow (Q 2262)](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2262) and at [Meta Stack Exchange(Q 256587)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256587), where it finally was recommended to ask it here.

The question is about the "cite" feature available on some (but not all) Stack Exchange sites, like Math Overflow, math.stackexchange, etc.  This question is not about extending the feature to other sites.

### Background:

The [FindStat](http://www.findstat.org/) project encourages contributors to provide references for combinatorial statistics.

I am currently redesigning the way such references are processed.  In future, a contributor should only type something like `[[arxiv:1234.5678]]` or `[[MO168885]]`, without providing any further information.  The program then will fetch author and title from the various websites.  This was (relatively) easy for the arXiv, but for Math Overflow citations (which occur a lot, by nature of the site), I'm hitting a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty easy to get the bibtex, just send a `GET` request formatted like so:

```
https://mathoverflow.net/posts/{POST NUMBER}/citation
```

For example, for [this Math Overflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105922/von-neumann-algebra-associated-to-the-infinite-cuntz-algebra), you can get the bibtex for the question and top 2 answers with:

- [mathoverflow.net/posts/105922/citation](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/105922/citation) (Question)
- [mathoverflow.net/posts/105930/citation](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/105930/citation) (Answer 1)
- [mathoverflow.net/posts/105929/citation](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/105929/citation) (Answer 2)

---

The results are returned in a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
  "bibtex":   "@MISC {105929,\r\n    TITLE = {Von Neumann algebra associated to the infinite Cuntz algebra},\r\n    AUTHOR = {Ollie Margetts (https://mathoverflow.net/users/10779/ollie-margetts)},\r\n    HOWPUBLISHED = {MathOverflow},\r\n    NOTE = {URL:https://mathoverflow.net/q/105929 (version: 2013-07-28)},\r\n    EPRINT = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/105929},\r\n    URL = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/105929}\r\n}",
  "amsref":   "\\bib\\{105929}{misc}{    \r\n    title={Von Neumann algebra associated to the infinite Cuntz algebra},    \r\n    author={Ollie Margetts (https://mathoverflow.net/users/10779/ollie-margetts)},    \r\n    note={URL: https://mathoverflow.net/q/105929 (version: 2013-07-28)},    \r\n    eprint={https://mathoverflow.net/q/105929},    \r\n    organization={MathOverflow}  \r\n}",
  "example":  "<p><b>Example citation:</b></p><p>Ollie Margetts (https://mathoverflow.net/users/10779/ollie-margetts), Von Neumann algebra associated to the infinite Cuntz algebra, URL (version: 2013-07-28): https://mathoverflow.net/q/105929</p>"
}
```

The `bibtex` property contains the bibtex in a formatted string.  For example, the above prints out as:

```
@MISC {105929,
    TITLE = {Von Neumann algebra associated to the infinite Cuntz algebra},
    AUTHOR = {Ollie Margetts (https://mathoverflow.net/users/10779/ollie-margetts)},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {MathOverflow},
    NOTE = {URL:https://mathoverflow.net/q/105929 (version: 2013-07-28)},
    EPRINT = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/105929},
    URL = {https://mathoverflow.net/q/105929}
}
```